# Why do my games have "some" audio problems on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

Twice now, my Black Ops 3 game on Xbox One has lost "some" of it's sound effects.

The following are sounds that I've noticed are missing:

- Announcer Voice
- Winner Circle Talking
- My footsteps (maybe enemy footsteps as well)

I'm sure there's more that I'm not noticing, but it's very strange.

**However: If I plug in headphones into my controller, I can hear all noises perfectly fine!**

I tried to uninstall the game fully and reinstall it, didn't work.
I also tried to mess with the Xbox Audio Settings, no change.

I ended up formatting my console, and it **did** fix it. But it just happened again...

I don't know if it's related, but it was the first time I joined an Xbox Live Party since I formatted my box. So maybe something in Xbox Party has a bug?

**How can I fix my Black Ops 3 game so that I can hear all of the sound effects?**

**UPDATE**

I played a different game last night, and I am fairly certain it is also missing some of the audio. Most of it is there, but it seems to be missing certain sound effects. So this is not directly related to Black Ops 3, definitely something surrounding Xbox One.

Comment: Is it just when entering a Xbox Party?

Comment: It's tough to determine. Only way to find out would be to reformat my Xbox. Ensure audio works. Join a party, see if it's broken. But if you're asking if the audio is only broken when in a party, unfortunately not. Not that's messed up, it's always messed up, even when playing COD solo.

Comment: Have you entered a party prior to playing solo? Because I do know that when entering Xbox parties, the audio will adjust accordingly.

Comment: If I go home and turn on my Xbox right now, without entering an Xbox Party, the COD game will still be missing some of the audio mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am curious if entering a party is what caused the issue though.

Comment: Right, because I am aware that joining parties do in fact amend the audio. If you check the sound levels in game, without joining a party, do they have decreased bars?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36679/discussion-between-ardavis-and-sean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... so I discovered the solution, and it's a silly one. Make sure all of your speakers are plugged in.

I failed to mention that I was using 5.1 Surround Sound with my Xbox One. I just noticed that my front center speaker cable had come out of the speaker.

In games like Black Ops 3, all of the missing audio I mentioned in the question above only came out of that one speaker, hence why it was missing.